# Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' --TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, typescript-eslint

i have a two column mega menu and i want when user hover a category, that category items to be displayed dynamic on second column .

i'm using typescript, the problem is when i wanna update the `megaMenu` state i get a red underline saying `Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`
why is this happening ? i really appreciate some help.

```js
  const [megaMenu, setMegaMenu] = useState("");

return (
            <Grid onMouseEnter={(e) => setMegaMenu(e.target.innerText)} >
             ....
             ....
             ....
             ....
             ....

            </Grid>
)
```

Comment: You could specify the type of the event in the callback. Also are you using material-ui ?

Comment: @PratikWadekar Yes Its MUI Grid system. you mean like this ? ```onMouseEnter={(e): Event => setMegaMenu(e.target.innerText)}``` this also return an error ```Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Event'.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could type cast event target to `HTMLElement` and access `innerText` over it

```html
<Grid onMouseEnter={(e) => setMegaMenu((e.target as HTMLElement).innerText)} />
```